# Set a Breakpoint on a field in a Java class while debugging in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to set a break point on a field in a Java class while debugging using VS Code.

Either when the value of that field changes or when the field is accessed, I need the break point to be hit.

Comment: some debuggers support [data-breakpoints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_data-breakpoints)

Comment: Please add the details of the problem so that we can better help you solve the problem. Such as [the smallest reproducible case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the desired effect you want, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Field level breakpoints cannot be set for Java classes in Visual Studio code as of today.